# Discord.js v14 not fetching Game actitivty from server members

Tags: node.js, discord

I try to print to my console all server members (who are online) and their currently played game.

I can fetch the users and their ID (the check if they are online seems not to work) but not the game activity.

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');

// Erstelle einen neuen Discord-Client
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
  ],
});

const token = 'token';

client.once('ready', async () => {
    console.log('Bot ist bereit!');

    client.guilds.cache.each(async (guild) => {
        console.log(`Gilde: ${guild.name} (${guild.id})`);

        const members = await guild.members.fetch();

        members.each((member) => {
            console.log(`  Mitglied: ${member.user.tag} (${member.id})`);

            if (member.presence && member.presence.status === 'online') {

                if (member.user.presence.game) {
                    console.log(`    Aktuell gespieltes Spiel: ${member.user.presence.game.name}`);
                } else {
                    console.log(`    Das Mitglied spielt derzeit kein Spiel.`);
                }
            } else {
                console.log(`    Das Mitglied ist offline.`);
            }
        });
    });
});

client.login(token);
```

[image]

[image]

I tried to adapt solution from here: [Discord.js V14 Cron fetch all guild members from specified server and retrieve their details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74961691/discord-js-v14-cron-fetch-all-guild-members-from-specified-server-and-retrieve-t)

However this did not work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem:

```
client.once('ready', async () => {
    console.log('Bot ist bereit!');

    // Server anhand seiner ID abrufen
    const targetGuild = client.guilds.cache.get(targetGuildId);

    if (!targetGuild) {
        console.error(`Der Server mit der ID ${targetGuildId} wurde nicht gefunden.`);
        return;
    }

    // Mitglieder für diesen Server abrufen und in einer Variable speichern
    const members = await targetGuild.members.fetch();

    // Durch alle Mitglieder iterieren
    members.each((member) => {
        console.log(`  Mitglied: ${member.user.tag} (${member.id})`);

        // Überprüfen, ob das Mitglied online ist
        if (member.presence && member.presence.status === 'online') {
            // Überprüfen, ob das Benutzerobjekt Informationen über Aktivitäten enthält
            if (member.presence.activities && member.presence.activities.length > 0) {
                console.log(`    Aktivitäten:`);
                member.presence.activities.forEach((activity, index) => {
                    console.log(`      Aktivität ${index + 1}: ${activity.name}`);
                });
            } else {
                console.log(`    Das Mitglied hat keine Aktivitäten.`);
            }
        } else {
            console.log(`    Das Mitglied ist offline.`);
        }
    });
});
```